# EF Core - How to setup many-to-many for same entity that already has a one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I currently have a one-to-many relationship between a `Post` and `Comment`. One `Post` can contain multiple `Comments`. What I want to do is create a many-to-many relationship for Comments. I also have a one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Comment`.

I.e. each `Comment` should be able to contain a collection of `Comment`. E.g. a user can comment on another user's comment. I want to preserve the ordering of comments so that I can display them in the correct order.

```
public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        //need to set this up
        public ICollection<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Post CommentForPost { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

What is the correct way of setting up this relationship while maintaining the one-to-many relationships I have with other entities?? Do I end up creating a join table? I'm not quite sure how I should be setting up my EF relationship to achieve above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each Comment should be able to contain a collection of Comment

```
public class Comment
{
 [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        //need to set this up
        public ICollection<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Post CommentForPost { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

   //this comment can be a child comment for (if is set) 
   // ParentCommentId is optional
           public string ParentCommentId {get;set;}
           public Comment ParentComment {get;set;}    
   //this comment can have many comments
           public ICollection<Comment> ChildComments {get;set;}

}
```

then for config. you can do:

```
 builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(x => x.ParentComment)
            .WithMany(x => x.ChildComments)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCommentId);
```

Comment: When you say parent comment is optional, what is the purpose of it? If I am inserting a comment into a post, I will be inserting it with the parentcommentid and parentcomment being null. Then if someone replies to that comment, I will insert it into the ChildComments. Is that the right approach?

Comment: ParentComment is optional, means that is not mandatory to set a value. Not all comments will have child comments. ChildComments you use when you want to get all child comments of a comment.

Comment: Gotcha. So in essence, the parentcommentid is set when I am inserting a child comment. If a user replies to a comment, set the reply as the child comment, and the parentcommentid as the comment they replied to. Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: When a user reply to a comment you just need to set to the reply the ParentCommentId egual with the Id of the comment

Comment: ah that makes sense. Just set the foreign key so that EF will take care of the rest. That makes sense. Thank you for the help and explanation

Comment: Thinking about this, above is not a many-to-many and is a one-to-many relationship right? A child comment is only related to a single parent comment and is not shared between other parent comments. I think I might have been thinking about this incorrectly when I first started out

Comment: Yes, is not many to many. A user cannot reply with same comment to 2 comments

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to confirm that. Thanks again for your help.