# How do I build many-to-many relationships on a class that has one reference list of the same type, with a linking object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm developing a note tracking application and need to have references between some notes. I'm using a Note class and an intermediary RelatedNote class to hold each one-to-one reference:

```cs
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedNote> RelatedNotes { get; set; }
}
public class RelatedNote
{
    public int Note1_Id { get; set; }
    public Note Note1 { get; set; }
    public int Note2_Id { get; set; }
    public Note Note2 { get; set; }
}
```

Since I set up the database using the code-first approach, I'm trying to use the fluent API to build the table. My process is to declare the clustered primary key, then define the ".HasOne().WithMany().HasForeignKey()" relationship.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedNote>()
    .HasKey(rn => new { rn.Note1_Id, rn.Note2_Id });

modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedNote>()
    .HasOne(n => n.Note1)
    .WithMany(rn => rn.RelatedNotes)
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.Note1_Id);
```

But that creates a table with 3 columns: Note1_Id, Note2_Id, and Note2Id. The first and last columns contain the Id of the notes.
[image: generated link table]

But I don't understand two aspects of the resulting table:

1. Why are there three columns and not just two?
2. Why does EF name the column that holds the second Note Id as "Note2Id" instead of using "Note2_Id" (same naming convention as the first column?).

I have already created a many-to-many relationship with two other classes (Author class - AuthorGroup class - Group class) which resulted in a two-column linking table.
Are three columns really necessary for this kind of link on one class?
And if possible, is there a way I can describe the relationship between the linked Notes with a string or byte to say that Note1 is a "parent" of Note2?

Comment: You can look at my answer to a similar question, to find how to set your entities. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54603697/4771606

Comment: RelatedNote has a Mapping for Note1, but no mapping for the navigation property Note2. Without the mapping of the FK, EF expects Note2_Id to be just an ordinary column and adds a new FK for the navigation property. Also note that you don't have to handle the joining table entities yourself: you could just use HasMany().WithMany(), even with some additional mapping if you require.

Comment: @LucianBumb I think your answer is probably the way to go for my project. I setup my Note class with parent and child note properties like your answer. But whenever I try to use the HasOne().WithMany() mapping, WithMany() doesn't recognize any of the properties in the note class and only shows methods of ICollection.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I tried having a mapping for Note2 as well, but the EF (compiler/engine?) complains of there already being a relationship between Note1 and RelatedNote. I'm guessing because Note1 and Note2 are of the same type anyway.

Comment: @LucianBumb Regarding my previous comment, I've figured out why the lambda expressions weren't working. I set the type of the parent note to ICollection instead of Note. T_T. Your suggestion, my first real solution from this site, worked! It also keeps my code and database simpler/cleaner. Thank you so much XD